# c# - Get control of Popup window, Windows 10

Tags: c#, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have a problem with UIAutomation using C#.
On Windows 10 after clicking link in tested app, popup is shown and i can't get control of it.

Picture below: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMQd6.jpg)

My code to get it below:

```
AutomationElement ele = null;
        while (ele == null)
        {
            try {
                ele = AutomationElement.RootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Subtree, new PropertyCondition(WindowPattern.IsModalProperty, true));


                Console.WriteLine(ele.Current.Name);

            } catch (NullReferenceException) {


            }
```

Comment: Just simulating an enter keypress doesn't solve this problem?

Comment: @GabrielDuarte it'll solve my problem, but i should use Thread.Sleep with unknown time for waiting popup and then simulate keypress. it will be last solution. But i try to find more proper (or correct) way to solve this problem. Sorry for my bad English(